# decodeURI not fully working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove the URI encoding from a link, but decodeURI doesn't seem to be fully working.

My example link is this: `/linkout?remoteUrl=http%253a%252f%252fsandbox.yoyogames.com%252fgames%252f171985-h-a-m-heroic-armies-marching`

After running the JavaScript script, it looks like this:

```
http%3a%2f%2fsandbox.yoyogames.com%2fgames%2f171985-h-a-m-heroic-armies-marching
```

How can I get rid of the remaining not correct codes in the URI?

My decoding code:

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');            // get the href
var href = decodeURI(href.substring(19));   // remove the outgoing part and remove the escaping
$(this).attr('href', 'http://'+href)        // change link on page
```

Comment: use decodeURIComponent() instead

Comment: Please also note that constructing the "$(this)" object twice in a single execution pass isn't a good idea, so cache it once at the beginning of the function and using the cached object whenever required.

Comment: `$(this).attr('href')` is just a longer, slower way to write `this.href`.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

the url looks as it was encoded twice, I also suggest to use decodeURIComponent

```
decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent("http%253a%252f%252fsandbox.yoyogames.com%252fgames%252f171985-h-a-m-heroic-armies-marching"))
```

results in:
"http://sandbox.yoyogames.com/games/171985-h-a-m-heroic-armies-marching"

but you should check why you have the url encoded twice in advance

Comment: -.- got lost on re-indenting... thanks for the hint :) comment +1

Comment: It's not my website I'm writing this code for, it's for a UserScript. I have no idea why they're double encoding the URI, I'll ask them sometime.

Comment: anyway doing decodeURIComponent twice should solve your problem :)

Answer (score 2):

My implementation is a recursive function:

```
export function tryDecodeURLComponent(str: string, maxInterations = 30, iterations = 0): string {
    if (iterations >= maxInterations) {
        return str;
    } else if (typeof str === 'string' && (str.indexOf('%3D') !== -1 || str.indexOf('%25') !== -1)) {
        return tryDecodeURLComponent(decodeURIComponent(str), maxInterations, iterations + 1)
    }

    return decodeURIComponent(str);
}
```

- `str`: encoded string.
- `maxInterations`: Maximum recursive iterations to try decoding `str` (*default: `30`*).
- `iterations`: Flag counter iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this situation in an ASHX handler for the PUT verb. ASP.NET is apparently encoding my XML for me, so my server-side call to *HttpUtility.UrlEncode* was not needed. Fixing it by calling client-side Javascript *decodeURI* twice -- is closing the barn door after the cows have already left and the HTTP I was sending was a protocol violation.

I would have commented and plus-one'd Tobias Krogh's answer, but I don't have the points to do so…

However, I still think that it is important to note that the failure being discussed here is not a Javascript decodeURI or anything else -- it is a data validation error.